# Practical examples/implementation details for Gauss-Seidel method

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, examples-counterexamples, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm having a presentation on Gauss-Seidel iterative method, and although it isn't mandatory
, I would like to have some practical examples for this method (a system of linear equations with n>=1000, preferrably in .txt form), as well as some implementation details (maybe block GS or something, since I haven't looked that up).

I would love it if you can give me examples from real-world calculations, like in a scientific paper or something.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Block Gauss-Seidel Iterative Method have been used to calculate steady state probabilities of a queueing system (especially queues defined as 2D Markov chains) by solving balance equations simultaneously. Here is a paper says so.

**Chakka, Ram. "Spectral expansion solution for some finite capacity queues." Annals of Operations Research 79 (1998): 27-44.**

Answer (score 0):

There is a Gauss-Seidel variant of the classical value iteration algorithm in dynamic programming, which improves the (naive) convergence rate of VI. Bertsekas has a good discussion of this in *Dynamic Programming and Optimal Control* (Vol II), Section 2.2.2.